# Matching end tags in Ruby

Tags: ruby

To learn Ruby, I'm implementing different data structures starting with nodes and a simple stack. If I matching each `def` with a corresponding end, there are lots of error about expecting $end (EOF) but getting `end`. So I could fix it by stacking some `end`s at the end of the class, but obviously I don't know why that works.

```
require "Node"
class Stack
    attr_accessor :top

    def size
            @size
    end

    def push(node)
        if node && node.next
            node.next = top
            top = node
        end
        size++
    def pop()
        if top != nil
            top = top.next
        end
        size--


    def to_s
        if top != nil
            temp = top
            while temp != nil
                puts temp.value
                temp = temp.next
            end
        else
            puts "The stack is empty"
        end
    end
end
end
end
```

The node class is very simple and shouldn't cause any problems:

```
class Node
    attr_accessor :next
    def initialize(value)
        @value = value
    end
end
```

Everything works fine on that Frankenstein Stack, except pushing a node results in `NoMethodError: undefined method +@' for nil:NilClass`. Not sure if that is related, but I'm mostly concerned with the syntax of method/class declaration and using `end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get an error because ruby does not have `++` and `--` operators.

Ruby understand the following constructs

```
size++
def pop()
# and
size--
def to_s()
```

like

```
size + +def pop()
# and 
size - -def to_s()
```

Ruby syntax is expression-oriented and method definition is expression in Ruby. Method definition expressions (`def pop()` and `def to_s()`) are evaluated to `nil` (in your code you actually define method `pop` inside `push` method body and `to_s` inside `pop` method body). And this is why you get `NoMethodError: undefined method +@' for nil:NilClass` error - it evaluates expression `size + +nil` and nil does not define unary plus operator. In this expression first `+` is an `Fixnum` addition operator (`size` is `Fixnum`), and second `+` is unary plus operator of `nil` (result of `def pop()` expression).

Use `+= 1` and `-= 1` instead of `++` and `--`. Your code should look like this:

```
class Stack
    attr_accessor :top

    def size
            @size
    end

    def push(node)
        if node && node.next
            node.next = top
            top = node
        end
        @size += 1 # @size, not `size` because you have `size` getter and you cannot modify size with getter method
    end

    def pop()
        if top != nil
            top = top.next
        end
        @size -= 1
    end

    def to_s
        if top != nil
            temp = top
            while temp != nil
                puts temp.value
                temp = temp.next
            end
        else
            puts "The stack is empty"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `def`s don’t have a matching `end`. Also, Ruby does not have a `++` operator; you’ll have to use `+= 1` instead.

Comment: According to the question, OP had those `end`s where they belong, but it gave him syntax errors. That's why he removed them (that wasn't the wisest decision).

Comment: @NiklasB.: Of course, the OP is incorrect in his assumption.  The Ruby parser works per spec, the syntax error was somewhere else or he counted his def/end pairs wrong.

Comment: @Ed S.: Yeah, the syntactic problem is the `++` and possibly the use of `next` as a method name (not sure of that, though).

Comment: The reason that it was giving the errors even though I had the correct end tags was it was confused by the `size++` and was interpreting as the above answer described. It's the little things...